# How to fill a WPF ComboBox based on another ComboBox? I am using web API for getting the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, data-binding

I have two ComboBoxs:

```
<Label Content="Product Code :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="359,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
        <ComboBox Width="200"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  x:Name="cmbAlpha"
                  SelectedValue="seletectedItem"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding cmbContent}" Margin="564,148,0,0" />

        <Label Content="Numeric Code :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="359,218,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
        <ComboBox Width="200"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  x:Name="cmbNum"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding cmbContent}" Margin="564,218,0,0"/>
```

[image]

The product code mentioned in this image is alphanumeric code. The alphanumeric code is getting data from the following code:

```
public IncomingProductWeight()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            alphaCode();
            numCode();
        }

private void alphaCode()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://qa.n-1.info/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
               new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/GetProductCodeList?token=!v*8eJ4?z%MMV!qWf!$JAKF@6Akk*!6*f9_mSjLG?2bS__!ab@").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var incomings = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Incoming>>().Result;
                cmbContent = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                foreach (var item in incomings)
                {
                    cmbContent.Add(item.AlphanumericCode);
                }
                InitializeComponent();

                cmbAlpha.ItemsSource = cmbContent;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

The numeric code ComboBox will fill after selecting an alphanumeric code from the alphanumeric code ComboBox. One or more numeric codes will display against an alphanumeric code.

```
private void numCode()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://qa.n-1.info/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
               new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string tempGet = "api/GetfilteredIncomingNumericCodesByAlphanumericCode?token=!v*8eJ4?z%MMV!qWf!$JAKF@6Akk*!6*f9_mSjLG?2bS__!ab@&alphanumericCode=" + SelectedAlphaCode();
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(tempGet).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var incomings = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Incoming>>().Result;
                cmbContent = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                foreach (var item in incomings)
                {
                    cmbContent.Add(item.NumericCode);
                }
                InitializeComponent();

                cmbNum.ItemsSource = cmbContent;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }

private string SelectedAlphaCode()
        {
            cmbAlpha.SelectedValue = cmbAlpha.SelectedValue;
            return cmbAlpha.Text;
        }
```

The API for getting the alphanumeric code:

```
public JsonResult GetProductCodeList(string token)
        {
            var items = this.productCodeService.GetDistinctProductCodes().Where(x => x.Status == "Active");

            if (token != Startup.globalToken)
            {
                return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }

            return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

The API for getting the numeric code:

```
public JsonResult GetfilteredIncomingNumericCodesByAlphanumericCode(string token, string alphanumericCode)
        {
            var filteredCodeList = productCodeService.GetProductCodes()
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AlphaNumericCode)
                && x.AlphaNumericCode.Equals(alphanumericCode) && x.Status == "Active" && x.IsIncoming == "Yes").ToList();
            if (token != Startup.globalToken)
            {
                return Json(filteredCodeList, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }
            return Json(filteredCodeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Using the above API, I get the data. See the image below:
[image]

How can I show the numeric code for the specific alphanumeric code in the Wpf application? I've searched and applied different logic but couldn't do that.

Comment: I applied DisplayMemberPath, but it didn't work in my case.